# Eclipse installation and setup

Tags: eclipse, installation

Recently installed Eclipse, for work on a school project, and I am having a little bit of an issue getting it to work properly, im sure its just me being unfamilar with this new IDE, I did some research before posting this and it seems that the issue is I havent configured any launch options, but i am not entirely sure how to go about doing that

it says "the selection cannot be launched and, there are no recent launches"

here is my code, its just a very basic test code to see if i set it up correctly.

```
package lesson1;
public static void main(String args[])
{   
       System.out.println("Hello World");  

}
```

also I notice that my "autocomplete" function is not working, as it should be.

I am MUCH more comfortable twith microsoft's visual studio, can that be used to develop Java applications? Do any pluggins allow that?

Comment: I have changed/extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checklist:

- JDK installed and running (not only JRE)
- Eclipse for Java (a package with JDT - Java Development Tools)
- created a "Java Project", not a just a simple "Project"
- created a class
- added a static main method to this class:

  ```
  package lesson1;

  public class FirstClass {

      public static void main(String args[])
      {   
          System.out.println("Hello World");  
      }

  }
  ```

  (in a file called FirstClass.java in folder/package lesson1)
- select the view with that class and press `F11` (menu: Run -> Debug)
  . This should create a run configuration and execute the main method.

Comment: I have made the modifications you reccomended, but it still is not even compiling

Comment: yes same error, I assume it measn it isnt compiling, becuase i have no launch options configured, and I quite frankly will need my hand held setting up launch options. I dont want to do anything fancy with it at the moment i just want ti to compile and run

Comment: see i do that and the "run " button at the bottom is greyed out

Comment: any error in the problems view (show by pressing `Alt-Shift-Q` and `X`)?

Comment: Maybe follow the tutorial: Menu Help -> Welcome -> Tutorials -> Create a hello World application